# I'm trying to get intuit request token but get a 401 Unauthorized error (oauth_problem=token_rejected)

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

My authorization token is:

```
oauth_token=""
,oauth_nonce="<unique id>"
,oauth_consumer_key="<consumerKey>"
,oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"
,oauth_timestamp="<epoch timestamp>"
,oauth_version="1.0"
,oauth_signature="<generated signature>"
```

(one line, but it has been formatted for legibility)

to generate the signature I run the algorithm using the following message:

```
POST&https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token&oauth_token="",oauth_nonce="<unique id>",oauth_consumer_key="<consumerKey>",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="<epoch timestamp>",oauth_version="1.0"
```

against my OAuth Consumer Secret and an empty string, like:

```
"<consumerSecretKey>&<empty>"
```

, empty because I'm still requesting the access tokens.

then I do a POST
URL:

```
https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token?oauth_callback=<myCallbackURL>
```

Header:

```
Authorization :OAuth <authorizationToken>
```

Body:

```
<authorizationToken>
```

After this rather get the request tokens I get an 401 Unauthorized error (oauth_problem=token_rejected)

Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

The get request token call is a GET call.
This is a sample raw request/response-

GET https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token?oauth_callback=oob&oauth_nonce=34562646-ab97-46e1-9aa7-f814d83ef9d1&oauth_consumer_key=qyprd7I5WvVgWDFnPoiBh1ejZn&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1392306961&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=0EtvSnzsuumeyib2fiEcnSyu8%3D HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth.intuit.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 15:56:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 150
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

oauth_token_secret=dXhHHMS1EfdrQ32UabOMscIRWt5bLJNX3ZKljjBc&oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_token=qyprdbwXdWrAt0xM2NgkLlJ79yCp4I2SmDg7tahDBPjA6Wti